# G/H is cyclic if H is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Let $G \leq S_5$ and let $a=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ and $b=(1\ 4 \ 5\ 2)$ be two elements of $G$.
Let $H=<a>$.
I can prove that $H\triangleleft G$ but I need to prove that $G/H$ is cyclic and give its order.
any ideas ?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried (a) computing elements of the group to see what you get; or (b) - knowing that you have $a^5=b^4=1$ looking for another relation between $a$ and $b$; (c) trying to identify what the group might be from what you know of its order; (d) considering what you know about odd and even permutations to inform your analysis of the structure? If you know $H$ is normal in $G$, what data did you use to prove that, and what information can you get from the calculations you have already done?

Comment: Why the -1, people, be constructive and at least put a comment to say why the -1, otherwise we can't improve :D

Comment: The $-1$ is from me because you not said what the group $G$ is. If you correct this I will delete the downvote.

Comment: @Derek, I have no more than what I said in my question. This is the whole exercice...

Comment: But the question cannot be answered in its present form. You cannot prove anything about $G$ without specifying what $G$ is! (I can guess what the question should  be, but it is up to you to get it right!)

Comment: @Derek yes It can. please remove the -1. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer half the question.

$a^5=b^4=(aba^{-1})^{3}$ so $3\times 4 \times 5\ |\ |G|$
so $|G|\in \{60, 120\}$ .
by Lagrange Theorem : $|G|=|H|\ |G/H|$ and we know that $|H|=5$
so  $|G/H|\in \{12, 24\}$
by the CRT:$ G/H \cong Z/12Z$ or $ G/H \cong Z/24Z$ so $G/H$ is cyclic

The other half is to know the exact order of $G/H$. Any help is much appreciated.